# How to send an automated email with PHP that summarizes data from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, email

I am trying to write a PHP script that will grab data from the PostgreSQL database (which stores statistics on the performance of our company's services) and then convert it into an email that summarizes the data in an HTML email.

I need some help getting started - how do I create the recurring email (which sends out a "digest" to the company team on a daily basis) and how would I request the data from the database?

I have minimal knowledge in databases and PHP (I generally do front-end and design work) so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You should remove the "mysql" tag, as this question is about a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Learn about cron - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron to have reoccouring tasks. Learn about phpmailer to create your html emails - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: This is extremely broad and does not demonstrate any efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started:

1. [Connecting to a PostgreSQL database and querying](http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php)
2. [Sending an e-mail (using PHPMailer)](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial#2)

About making the mail "recurrent": Usually the thing to do is to write a script, and then schedule it for repeated execution. You could call the script using cron (if under Linux/UNIX) or something equivalent under other OS. You might need to talk to a sysadmin in order to set that up.

If you need assistance with the SQL query, please post the structure of the tables involved.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm new to Stack Overflow and didn't realize the vagueness of my question. I will follow up if I have a specific error or problem.